# JarJar'ed artefact and Maven deploy process

Tags: java, android, maven

I am currently developing an SDK targetting both servers and Android devices.
My deliverable JAR is JarJar'ed, thus preventing any dependency leaks from happening in client apps (using maven-jarjar-plugin).

However, there is one issue that puzzles me. A standard Maven deploy will ship sources, POM and other things. The problem is that any Maven-compatible build tool (e.g.: Gradle) will first resolve our SDK according to the deployed POM, thus triggering the pointless downloads of my SDK dependencies (remember: they are JarJar'ed in the final JAR!).

How can I deploy my SDK so that any build tool will understand there is nothing but the SDK to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That strange, I'm surprised if the jar jar plugin doesn't support it natively. You may give a try to the shade plugin which is also allowing to relocate classes and for sure it creates and deployed a modified pom for your artifact that won't expose your embedded dependencies to others projects using yours.

See :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom

cheers